# changing the shape of a jpeg

Tags: flash, adobe

I want to change a photograph from a square or rectangle to a trapezoid so I can use it in Flash as part of a sequence that shows a card or hard-cover book opening. I consider myself a novice using any of the Adobe software so if you are able to phrase your answer accordingly, that would be extremely helpful.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called image "masking".  One of the important things to know is, what version of Flash are you using?  If you are using an old version of Flash it might be a little different than it is with the current versions.  I would point you to a tutorial for this, but without knowing the exact Flash version you are using, the directions might not be accurate.

Basically what you need to do is make two layers, one with the image, and another with the shape, you make the shape layer the masking layer, and then the image will only show what you can see through the shape/mask.

Also, this might help you out:
http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/using/using-mask-layers.html